# asp.net mvc 2 custom service account

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, silverlight-4.0, web-deployment

I'm trying to deploy ASP.NET MVC 2 Silverlight application with custom service account. I did the following:

1) Domain user account (myAppUser) was created. Domain controller is different from the web server to which  I'm trying to deploy my app.

2) On the web server I run the following command:
  aspnet_iisreg -ga myDomain\myAppUser
which assigned myAppUser to IIS_WPG group

3) In IIS manager I created application pool and configured that pool to run under myAppUser account.

4) I deployed my web app using VS 2010's publish method and configured so that it uses the above application pool.

5) in web.config I have

```
identity impersonate="false"
authentication mode="Windows"
```

When I requested the default page it displays login page; what I want is silent login using the credentials of the client machine. How can I do that?

PS: actually it didn't ask credentials under default Network Service Account. When I changed that account to myAppUser it started asking credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link might be helpful for you:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/authenticating-users-with-windows-authentication-vb